# setBackgroundResource when changing Activities

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imagebutton

In one of my activities I have an `ImageButton` that on click changes the background resource by using `setBackgroundResource()`. I works fine in that activity but when I leave that activity and come back to it the button has changed back to its default background that was set in the XML. Is there a way to permanently set the background resource to something until the button is clicked again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to store the value on the image button in a static variable or SharedPreferences,

For example declare a variable

```
public static int bgresource;
```

now on the img button click

```
if(something) {
bgresource = R.drawable.img1
} else {
bgresource = R.drawable.img2
}

mylayout.setBackgroundResource(bgresource);
```

and also do the following in onResume() of the activity:

```
mylayout.setBackgroundResource(bgresource);
```

Comment: When I put in  layout.options.setBackgroundResource(bgresource); in the img button click it gives me an error that says, "cannot invoke setBackgroundResource(int) on the primitive type int." Any solution?

Answer (score 1):

Use SharedPreferences.
When changing the Background:

```
getSharedPreferences("background", MODE_PRIVATE).edit().putString("background","background_nr_1").commit();
```

or

```
getSharedPreferences("background", MODE_PRIVATE).edit().putString("background","background_nr_2").commit();
```

and so on. This will save the string, describing your current background to sharedPreferences.

In the onCreate-Method you need to put:

```
String back = getSharedPreferences("background", MODE_PRIVATE).getString("background");
```

This will get you "background_nr_x" in back.
Now you can choose the background:

```
if (back.equals("background_nr_1") { // set the Background associated with nr_1
else if (.... "nr_2") ...
```

Note: this will restore the current chosen background, even if the App was closed.

Answer (score 0):

Save the URL/id of the image you use as background in SharedPreferences and make sure to set it everytime the activity is created. Otherwise the background specified in your XML file will be used when the activity is created the next time.

Answer (score 0):

You should overwrite your Activity `onResume()` method. 
Make your activity or button keep the state (pressed or not pressed) and, at the `onResume()` method, check this state and change the background.

Comment: I have never done an on resume. Does that go below the on create?

Comment: @Zach: Yes, it's called right after the onCreate method. When your activity pauses (when another activity comes to foerground, but not stopping your current activity), at returning to it the onCreate won't be called, but onResume will. Take a look to the API doc for Activity, where the Activity life cycle is described (link http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a trick like this:

```
    //outside the onCreate:
    boolean resourceIsSet = false;

    //inside the onCreate:
    if(!resourceIsset) {
        setBackgroundResource();
        resourceIsset= true;
    }
```

Or you can use a [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) as other suggested